# Exporting Managed Properties in SharePoint 2010 via a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I’m running this script I found on technet.

Export Managed/Crawled Properties from Enterprise Search
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-ManagedCrawled-7548d31b

Why am I receiving the following error below?

PS C:> .\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty : SearchApplication Search Service not found.
At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:14 char:67
+ $ManagedPropreties = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty <<<<  -SearchApplication $SearchServiceApp
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...ManagedProperty:GetSearchMetadataManagedProperty) [Get-S
   PEnterpris...ManagedProperty], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.GetSearchMetadataManagedProperty

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:28 char:32
+     $Mappings = $MP.GetMappings <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetMappings:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:33 char:29
+             if ($CP.Contains <<<< (":") -eq $true){
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Contains:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:>

=======================================================================

Environment –
Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
64-bit

> $PSVersionTable
>   Name                           Value
>   PSVersion                      2.0
>
> $host
>   Name             : ConsoleHost
>   Version          : 2.0
>   UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
>
> Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -local
>   TypeName        : SharePoint Server Search
>   Description     : Index content and serve search queries
>   Role            : None
>   Status          : Online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue.  I needed to change the parameter for $SearchServiceApp to "Search Service Application".